# three.js with raycaster in typescript (mouse hover)

Tags: typescript, three.js, 3d

I'am a beginner in three.js. I have implemented this example of raycaster with mouse hover in java script https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/52ejur45/ . But, when I try to do this in typescript it doesn't work. The raycaster with mouse hover only works when clicked and dragged using Orbit controller in typescript. I have provided both java script and typescript codes. Can anyone help me to find out a solution.

```
Java script code : 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>three.js raycaster</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<meta name="referrer" content="origin-when-cross-origin" />

        <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script type="module">


        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var mesh,controls;
        var cube;
        var mouse = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },
        INTERSECTED;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
            camera.position.z = 500;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var pointlight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff,0.5);
            var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.4);
            camera.add( pointlight, light);
            light.position.set( 10, 10, 0 );
            pointlight.position.set( 10, 10, 0 );
            scene.add(camera);

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(20, 20, 20);
            for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff }));
                object.position.x = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
                object.position.y = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
                object.position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
                scene.add(object);
            }

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
            renderer.setClearColor("#00a9d4", 1);
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
            mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
            console.log(mouse.x,mouse.y);
        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            render();
            update();

        }

        function update() {
            var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y, 1);
            console.log(vector);
            vector.unproject(camera);
            var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
            var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(scene.children);
            if (intersects.length > 0) {
                console.log(intersects.length);
                if (intersects[0].object != INTERSECTED) {
                    if (INTERSECTED)
                        INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(INTERSECTED.currentHex);
                    INTERSECTED = intersects[0].object;
                    INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();
                    INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(0xffff00);
                }
            } else {
            }

        }

        function render() {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

```
Typescript code:

import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'mousehover';

  @ViewChild('canvas', null)
  private canvasRef: ElementRef;

  public mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };

  INTERSECTED;
  public camera; scene; controls;
  public raycaster;
  public renderer; directionallight;




  private getAspectRatio(): number {
    let height = this.canvas.clientHeight;
    if (height === 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    return this.canvas.clientWidth / this.canvas.clientHeight;
  }

  private get canvas(): HTMLCanvasElement {
    return this.canvasRef.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.init();
    this.animate();
  }

  init() {
    this.canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
    this.canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    this.camera.position.x = 0;
    this.camera.position.y = 0;
    this.camera.position.z = 100;
    this.directionallight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    this.directionallight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    this.camera.add(this.directionallight);
    this.scene.add(this.camera);
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(20, 20, 20);
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
      var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff }));
      object.position.x = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
      object.position.y = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
      object.position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
      this.scene.add(object);
    }
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, canvas: this.canvas });
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.renderer.setClearColor("#79bff3", 1);
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  }

  onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
    this.mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
    this.mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    this.mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  }

  animate() {
    try {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate());
      this.render();
      this.update();
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log("animate error. " + err.message);
    }
  }

  update() {
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y, 1);
    vector.unproject(this.camera);
    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(this.camera.position, vector.sub(this.camera.position).normalize());
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(this.scene.children);
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
      console.log(intersects.length);
      if (intersects[0].object != this.INTERSECTED) {
        if (this.INTERSECTED)
          this.INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(this.INTERSECTED.currentHex);
        this.INTERSECTED = intersects[0].object;
        this.INTERSECTED.currentHex = this.INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();
        this.INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(0xffff00);
      }
    } else {
    }
  }

  render() {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working? You code works for me (without the angular pieces), I'm wondering if there are external pieces not described here that are changing things.

Comment: In typescript, When mouse hover mesh particle does not changes color but when clicked and dragged the color changes.In java script it's working fine.